# How to check if user is in the main page(Zend FrameWork)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need to hide some  item in the view when the page is main, others page will show this item

so what function i need to use to check if the page is main

Comment: There is a big difference between ZF1 and ZF2. What version do you use?

Comment: i am trying to use the $this->url(), but it returns / in all the pages, how can i check using those functions if the page == '/', or page == 'some_page'?

Comment: the main page you mean the index page you are talking about?

Comment: I have post one answer let me know if its work for you...

Comment: Please paste your code so its easy to understood...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the current controller and action name with following code,

```
$controller = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
$action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

for main page you can put condition where controller is "index" and action is "index"
 you code should execute or not to execute 
thats alll..............

If you are not in controller user

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

Comment: but when i use it in the view it gives me an error, can make that check in the view without the controller?